# How to use a dependency of a module within a Play app

Tags: module, playframework, dependencies, playframework-1.x

I am writing a Play Framework module in order to share some common logic among multiple Play apps. One of the things I would like my module to do is provide some frequently-used functionality by way of 3rd-party modules, for example the excellent [Markdown module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/markdown).

First of all, is it possible to do this? I want all the apps that include my module to be able to use the `.markdown().raw()` String extension without needing to explicitly declare the Markdown module as a dependency. The [Play Framework Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/play-framework-cookbook/book) chapter 5 seems to imply that it is possible, unless I am reading it wrong.

Secondly, if it is possible, how does it work? I have created the following vanilla example case, but I'm still getting errors.

I created a new, empty application "myapp", and a new, empty module "mymod", both in the same parent directory. I then modified `mymod/conf/dependencies.yml` to:

```
self: mymod -> mymod 0.1

require:
    - play
    - play -> markdown [1.5,)
```

I ran `play deps` on mymod and it successfully downloaded and installed the Markdown module. Running `play build-module` also worked fine with no errors.

Then, I modified `myapp/conf/dependencies.yml` to:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - mymod -> mymod 0.1

repositories:
    - Local Modules:
        type: local
        artifact: ${application.path}/../[module]
        contains:
            - mymod
```

I ran `play deps` on myapp and it successfully found mymod, and generated the `myapp/modules/mymod` file, containing the absolute path to mymod.

I ran myapp using `play run` and was able to see the welcome page on http://localhost:9000/. So far so good.

Next, I modified `myapp/app/views/Application/index.html` to:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

${"This is _MarkDown_, by [John Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).".markdown().raw()}
```

I restarted myapp, and now I get the following error.

```
09:03:23,425 ERROR ~

@6a6eppo46
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /

Template execution error (In /app/views/Application/index.html around line 4)
Execution error occured in template /app/views/Application/index.html. Exception raised was MissingMethodException : No signature of method: java.lang.String.markdown() is applicable for argument types: () values: [].

play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.markdown() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:86)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
        at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:187)
        at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
        at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:660)
        at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:640)
        at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:695)
        at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:13)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.markdown() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at /app/views/Application/index.html.(line:4)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
        ... 13 more
```

And just to confirm I'm not crazy, I tried adding the `play -> markdown [1.5,)` line to `myapp/conf/dependencies.yml` and restarted the app, and confirmed that it works.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same problem, it seems that transitive dependencies through custom home made modules does not work